# Is there any way to Save baked texture with Filmic(View transform)?

Tags: rendering, texture-baking

The baked texture is very different from the color I saw in the viewport.

When I searched, it was said that the View Transform should be set to Standard, but I want to bake by applying a filmic feel.

Seniors in the world, please help me.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually it doesn't matter to what you set the *View Transform*, the texture bake will always have the colorspace sRGB after baking. It just might help that when you choose *View Transform* > *Standard*, the viewport will show the colors like they are in the texture bake.

If you want to apply the *Filmic* look to the texture bake, you have to apply it when saving the image texture. In the *Save As Image* dialogue box you can check the option *Save As Render*, this enables the option *Color Management* dropdown menu. If you use the default *Follow Scene*, the texture bake image will be saved with the *Filmic* settings of your scene. If you choose *Override* you can set new options for the image to be saved.

[image: save as render]

If you want to see the texture bake with the *Filmic* settings in the *Image Editor*, there is an option *View As Render* in the *Image* sidebar menu if you press <kbd>N</kbd>, but the settings there are only available after you have saved the image.

[image: view as render]

You just have to be aware, if you save the image texture with the *Filmic* settings instead of sRGB and you use it as texture in a scene where you have set the *Color Management* to *Filmic* as well, those settings will be on top of the already applied *Filmic* settings of the texture.

Comment: I'm so appreciative of your kind and detailed answer. I was able to solve the problem that I had been hanging on to all day.

Comment: By the way, It seems that the function of "Save as render" does not work when saving as "exr" format, but I wonder if that is the only way to save it.

Comment: No, this will only affect JPG or PNG file formats, since EXR saves in a kind of "raw" format simply spoken.

Comment: Thank you! I wish you all the best in the future.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that and would do it Nathan's way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a single pass.  You need two separate rendering passes to do this.

First, bake your texture image as non-color data and save as .exr to preserve the full color depth (upon which the filmic color transform will later act.)

Then you have two options.  The simplest is probably to put your saved image as a texture on a plane and render it, with Filmic color management, from an appropriately scaled orthographic camera, then save the image.  This will get you the color transform you want.

The other option is to set the sequencer to linear (in properties/render/color management/sequencer), enable compositing, and then enable composting nodes.  In compositing, use your new .exr as the image input rather than the render, then render and save.